# How to add time stamp on check of checkbox in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, checkbox

I just started playing with vuejs. My first app attempt is a todo app with add-todo,check-if-completed and delete functionalities.
 I want to add a time stamp whenever a user checks a task as completed but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: You can add this https://momentjs.com/. Just read the documentation.

Comment: Thank's Renato... Checked it out and it was helpful